# Unable to create session in jupyter notebook for keras kfold validation code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a code in jupyter notebook using keras/tensorflow. The code worked well when I ran it on my laptop that runs tensorflow on cpu but when I run the same code on my home computer that runs tensorflow on gpu I receive the message "failed to create session." I would like to keep using gpu if possible.

I will include my code and the error below along with the output from the terminal.

Code (I excluded other parts of the code that loads/ manipulate data):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

l2_reg = 0.4
momentum = 0.99
seed = 5

def create_model_val(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, layers=[20, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True):

    model = Sequential()

    # layer 1
    model.add(Dense(layers[0], input_dim=x_train.shape[1],
                    W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))

    if batch_norm == True:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))

    model.add(Activation(params['activation']))

    if dropout == True:
        model.add(Dropout(params['dropout']))

    # layer 2+    
    for layer in range(0, len(layers)-1):

        model.add(Dense(layers[layer+1], W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                        bias_initializer=bias_init))

        if batch_norm == True:
            model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))

        model.add(Activation(params['activation']))

        if dropout == True:
            model.add(Dropout(params['dropout']))

    # Last layer
    model.add(Dense(layers[-1], activation=params['last_activation'],
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))

    model.compile(loss=params['losses'],
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.adam(lr=params['lr']),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])





    model_output = {'model':model}

    return model_output


def train_and_evaluate_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val):
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                        validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
                        batch_size=params['batch_size'],
                        epochs=params['epochs'],verbose=0)
    return history




n_folds = 10
total_acc = []

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True)

for i, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(skf.split(x_main_normalized, y_main)):
        print("Running Fold", i+1, "/", n_folds)
        x_train_2, x_val_2 = x_main_normalized.iloc[train_idx], x_main_normalized.iloc[val_idx]
        y_train_2, y_val_2 = y_main.iloc[train_idx], y_main.iloc[val_idx]


        # have to change to one hot encode after split or else it yells at you *sadness*
        if params['losses']=='categorical_crossentropy':
            y_train_2 = to_categorical(y_train_2, num_classes=4)
            y_val_2 = to_categorical(y_val_2, num_classes=4)

        model = None # Clearing the NN.
        model = create_model_val(x_train_2, y_train_2, x_val_2, y_val_2, layers=[20, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True)

        history = train_and_evaluate_model(model['model'],x_train_2, y_train_2, x_val_2, y_val_2)

        history_dict = history.history
        train_acc = history_dict['acc']
        val_acc = history_dict['val_acc']
        last_acc = round(train_acc[-1],4)*100
        last_val_acc = round(val_acc[-1],4)*100

        total_acc.append([train_acc[-1], val_acc[-1]])

        print("Last training accuracy: " + str(last_acc)+'%' 
              + ", last validation accuracy: " + str(last_val_acc)+'%')
```

Jupyter notebook error message:

```
Running Fold 1 / 10
/home/mikedoho/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:19: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(20, input_dim=46, kernel_initializer="he_uniform", bias_initializer="he_uniform", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg...)`
/home/mikedoho/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:34: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(20, kernel_initializer="he_uniform", bias_initializer="he_uniform", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg...)`
/home/mikedoho/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:34: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(4, kernel_initializer="he_uniform", bias_initializer="he_uniform", kernel_regularizer=<keras.reg...)`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-db5ca8962dc5> in <module>()
     91                  batch_norm=True, dropout=True)
     92 
---> 93         history = train_and_evaluate_model(model['model'],x_train_2, y_train_2, x_val_2, y_val_2)
     94 
     95         history_dict = history.history

<ipython-input-24-db5ca8962dc5> in train_and_evaluate_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)
     64                         validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
     65                         batch_size=params['batch_size'],
---> 66                         epochs=params['epochs'],verbose=0)
     67     return history
     68 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1040                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1041                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1042                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1043 
   1044     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
    201                     outs = [outs]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2651 
   2652     def __call__(self, inputs):
-> 2653         if hasattr(get_session(), '_make_callable_from_options'):
   2654             if py_any(is_sparse(x) for x in self.inputs):
   2655                 if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_session()
    181                 config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_thread,
    182                                         allow_soft_placement=True)
--> 183             _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
    184         session = _SESSION
    185     if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
   1561 
   1562     """
-> 1563     super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
   1564     # NOTE(mrry): Create these on first `__enter__` to avoid a reference cycle.
   1565     self._default_graph_context_manager = None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, target, graph, config)
    631       if self._created_with_new_api:
    632         # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 633         self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
    634         # pylint: enable=protected-access
    635       else:

InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

Terminal message:

```
Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel effcd29a-2f4c-4e0e-8d39-f5993f09f90e
2018-08-15 18:48:40.171924: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-08-15 18:48:40.270262: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory reported: 11718230016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed at beginning of my code:

```
from keras import backend as K
cfg = K.tf.ConfigProto()
cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))
```

credit: http://forums.fast.ai/t/tip-clear-tensorflow-gpu-memory/1979/7