# Keras network training speed degradation

Tags: python, performance, keras, neural-network

Why does training of a Keras model take 
[more time](https://dokter.ai/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/training_speed_degradation.png) each time I build a new model in a Jupyter notebook. Quitting Jupyter/Python and restarting resets the training speed. [The scatterplot](https://dokter.ai/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/training_speed_degradation.png) looks the same each time I do this.

I'm using Keras 'Sequential' to train a plain MLP with an input layer of about 6000 features, 3 hidden relu-layers (size 2500, 800, 800) with batchnorm and dropout, and a sigmoid output, nothing special.

I'm optimizing (using GPyOpt, but the effect also appears when I'm building models in a simple for-loop), which I'm feeding a function that builds a new abovementioned Keras model each time it's referenced. Before the model is built in that function its calling the function limitmen() because otherwise I'm running into GPU-memory-issues:

```
def limit_mem():
    """
    Clear GPU-memory and tensorflow session.
    """
    K.get_session().close()
    cfg = K.tf.ConfigProto()
    cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))
```

I found this function after some searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868631/unable-to-create-session-in-jupyter-notebook-for-keras-kfold-validation-code) on stackoverflow

```
def f_beta(precision, recall, beta):
    f_beta_result = (1 + (beta ** 2)) * (precision * recall) / (((beta ** 2) * precision) + recall)
    if isinstance(f_beta_result, np.ndarray):
        f_beta_result[np.isnan(f_beta_result)] = 0
    else:
        if math.isnan(f_beta_result):
            f_beta_result = 0
    return f_beta_result

beta = 1.5  # define beta for f-score

class Metrics(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_f2s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []
        self.val_briers = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(X_val))).round()
        val_targ = y_val
        _val_precision, _val_recall, _val_f1, _support = precision_recall_fscore_support(val_targ, val_predict, labels=[0,1])
        _val_f2 = f_beta(_val_precision[1], _val_recall[1], beta)
        _val_brier = brier_score_loss(val_targ, val_predict)
#         print(_val_precision)
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1[1])
        self.val_f2s.append(_val_f2)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall[1])
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision[1])
        self.val_briers.append(_val_brier)
#         print (' — val_f1: %.3f — val_precision: %.3f — val_recall %.3f' % (    _val_f1[1], _val_precision[1], _val_recall[1]))
        return

    def return_metrics(self):
        return self.val_f1s, self.val_f2s, self.val_recalls, self.val_precisions, self.val_briers, np.array(self.val_f2s).argmax()

metrics = Metrics()

# create model
def build_model(dropout=0.9, dense1=2500, dense2=800, dense3=800, lr=0.0001):
    model = Sequential()

    # first layer
    model.add(Dense(dense1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init='uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # second layer
    model.add(Dense(dense2, init='uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # third layer
    model.add(Dense(dense3, init='uniform'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # final layer
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile model
    adam = Adam(lr)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy', 'mae'])
    return model
```

This is more or less the loop that builds keras models:

```
        for i in range(self.cycle):
            # actually build model
            t_before = time.time()
            self.keras_model = build_model(dropout, dense1, dense2, dense3, lr)

            # train model
            self.hist = self.keras_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=self.epochs, 
                                             batch_size=1024, verbose=0, callbacks=[metrics], 
                                             class_weight={ 0 : 1, 1 : weight1 })
            t_after = time.time()
```

Has anyone experienced the same? Do you need more information? Or is this a well known issue with a simple solution (or no solution at all)?

Comment: No, this is not a well known issue, you need to include a lot more information to get help.

Comment: I found 'K.clear_session()', never used that, Would that simply solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

did the [trick](https://dokter.ai/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/training_speed_degradation2-3.png).

For those of you that make tutorials: maybe its a good idea to add this at the end of the code.